# Problema para descargar PDF con Python

Tags: python, pdf

Estoy tratando de descargar este PDF:
https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scgli004/controlador?Destino=MuestraPDF&doctoID=6

Pero al visualizarlo me aparece un error de que el archivo no se puede abrir, creo que el problema es que necesito un usuario web temporal ya que si copia el URL y lo pego directamente en una ventana no me deja visualizarlo, solo puedo verlo si ingreso directamente en el portal, esta es la pagina principal:
 https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/menu/controlador?Destino=menu_gral.jsp

Pagina principal -> Precios vigentes de productos

este es mi codigo:

```
import urllib.request
import requests

url = 'https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scgli004/controlador?Destino=MuestraPDF&doctoID=1'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "Racks.pdf")

r = requests.get(url)

with open("Racks.pdf", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

Comment: La url es: https://www.comercialrefinacion.pemex.com/portal/scgli004/controlador?Destino=MuestraPDF&doctoID=1. Al mes la de Pagina principal -> Precios vigentes de productos